# C Array to Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address, dereference

Please explain why the below code fails at `line 10`.
How can I print values of `p`, i.e. `Hello World`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char ar[200] = "Hello World";
    strcat(ar, " !");
    printf("%s\n", ar);

    char **p = &ar;
    printf("%s\n", *p[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify more on what I want to achieve. I have a function that accepts `char**` as argument, hence why I want to convert `char ar[200]` into `char**`, but the application freezes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `printf("%s\n", (*p)[0]);` ?

Comment: @RoshDonniet OP wants to print the entire string through p

Comment: It's either `printf("%s\n", p[0]);` or `printf("%s\n", *p);`. By doing `printf("%s\n", *p[0]);`, the pointer to string `p` is dereferenced twice. Hence, `*p[0]` is a char, not a string.

Comment: @RoshDonniet, I have tried that but the program crashes at the end

Comment: The type of `&ar` is `char (*)[200]` (pointer to 200-element array of `char`), not `char **`.

Comment: @francis, the string is printed but the program crashes

Comment: Thanks @AnishSharma, that one works!

Comment: @JohnBode while the pointer type mismatch is true, it is probably not the reason of the crash. With both types (`char (*)[200]` and `char **`), dereferencing twice via `*p[0]`in the OP's code yields a `char` value of 72 (which will be adjusted to an `int`and be used by  `printf` as an address), not a `char *` -- the OP must only dereference once. Dereferencing once yields in both cases the numerical address of the array which is correct in both cases (!). The argument is just wrongly typed in the case of `char (*)[200]`, but the `printf` implementation shouldn't care. Oh, francis said that ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays already "decay" to the address of their first element in most contexts. This behavior differs from other variables, even from the other aggregates, structs. The reasons are rooted deep in the history of C (namely, no joke, in B<sup>1</sup>).

One of the contexts though where an array does *not* decay is when its address is taken: the address operator yields a pointer to array, not a pointer to pointer to char:

```
char arr[6] = "abcde";  // 5 letters plus '\0'
char (*parr)[6] = &arr; // pointer to array of 6 elements
```

Curiously enough, dereferencing this pointer twice yields the first char in the array, as if `parr` *were* a pointer to pointer to char. The reason is that `*parr` simply is the original array, and dereferencing *that* is quite normally its first element. This is likely the source of much confusion:

```
printf("%c", **parr);
```

Traditionally (i.e. in the 1970s) pointer was pointer, and their types didn't matter much. (There is a big difference though: What value does `parr+1` have?) But it's nice to compile without warnings and to understand what one is doing. So how do we get your requirement, a pointer to a pointer to a char, for printing `arr`? The answer is, just use a pointer to a pointer!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char ar[200] = "Hello World";
    strcat(ar, " !");
    printf("%s\n", ar);

    char *p = ar;  // pointer to char: 
                   // array "decays" to address of first char

    char **pp = &p;  // pp is a pointer to a pointer to char.
                     // The point is, it points to the "pointer to char" p.

    printf("%s\n", *pp); // *pp is what pp points to: 
                         // p, a simple pointer to char. That's what "%s"
                         // expects. p is initialized and points to 
                         // the first char in ar.

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Cf. the interesting paper by Dennis Ritchie, ["The Development of the C Language"](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.pdf), p.7

Answer (score 5):

You have declared a character array and assigned value to it. If you just mention the name of the array, you are actually mentioning the base address of this array. Pointers can store address, you can define a char pointer and assign the base address of your character array to it.

for example

```
char ar[200]="Hello World";
char *p=a; //assign the base address of a to p;
```

You can then print the string using the `%s` format specifier with the base address of your character array(string).

```
printf("%s",a);// print the string "Hello World". here a is the base address
printf("%s",p);//print the string "Hello World". here p is the base address
```

This will work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char ar[200] = "Hello World";
    strcat(ar, " !");
    printf("%s\n", ar);
    char *p = ar;
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

## Edited for your convenience

```
char *q=a;
char **P=&q;
printf("%s",*p);
```

if this is what you want

Comment: You should explain why it works and his code doesn't

Comment: @JohnColeman I appreciate your world and would really like to thank him

Answer (score 1):

In c `ar` is equal to `&ar`, because arrays are basically memory addresses to their first elements.
So you only need a pointer to a `char` not a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char ar[200] = "Hello World";
    strcat(ar, " !");
    printf("%s\n", ar);

    char *p = &ar;
    printf("%s\n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc     main.c   -o main
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:16: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     char **p = &ar;
                ^
main.c:10:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s\n", *p[0]);
     ^
```

`expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’` seems very clear :P

You can print your string by changing you program by

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char ar[200] = "Hello World";
    strcat(ar, " !");

    char *p = ar;
    printf("%s\n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is an interesting example of the difference between arrays and pointers. It is common to think of arrays as pointers, but that isn't quite true. The fact that `char ar[200]` *doesn't* make `ar` into a char pointer is why you can't use a `char**` to point to `ar`. On the other hand, arrays decay to pointers in function calls, so the following code *does* work (though it is terribly unmotivated):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printString(char ar[]){
    char **p = &ar; // as in original code
    printf("%s\n",*p);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char ar[200] = "Hello World";
    strcat(ar, " !");
    printf("%s\n", ar);

    printString(ar); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I print values of p, i.e. Hello World.

You do not need a pointer to pointer for this purpose. A simple pointer will do.

```
char *p;
p = ar;
printf ("%s\n",p);
```

Answer (score -1):

Example of when to use **pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char **bar)
{
  *bar = "some text";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *temp;

  foo (&temp);

  printf ("temp=%s\n", temp);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I explain in the comments of your code.

EDIT: **Do not copy following code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char ar[200] = "Hello World";// technically an array is a pointer, so char *ar and char[] are the same
    strcat(ar, " !");// pass the pointer to treat strings
    printf("%s\n", ar);// pass the pointer to treat strings

    char **p;// here is the problem you were giving the address of your pointer to a pointer of pointer in inline wich makes more confusing
    (*p) = &ar; // here is the correct assingment
    printf("%s\n", *p);// so here you should pass  *p
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: **This solution is far safer in real life situations**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char ar[200] = "Hello World";// technically an array is a pointer, so char *ar and char[] are the same
    strcat(ar, " !");// pass the pointer to treat strings
    printf("%s\n", ar);// pass the pointer to treat strings

    // This solution initializing is better because it avoids editing other variables
    char *p = ar;
    char **pp = &p;

    printf("%s\n", *pp);// so here you should pass  *pp
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(*p) = &ar;` this will dereference p, which is not initialized

Comment: A pointer doesn't need to be initialized because it points to an address in memory. Here is the test working properly: (https://ideone.com/cnM9Jn#stdin)

Comment: gcc complains:
test95.c:10:10: warning: ‘p’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Comment: can you cite the difference between `ar` and `&ar`??

Comment: @AnishSharma `ar` is a pointer because it is an array, while `&ar` is the address of this pointer, so `(*p) = &ar` says edit values p to point ar address

Comment: I downvoted. As it stands, it is terrible and should not be published. The sequence `char **p; (*p) = &ar;` writes to an arbitrary location in memory. It works only by chance. It will stop working Friday the 13th, or in the year 10000, or one second after 9:59:59, but only in locales with 24 hour time format. It is * **terrible** *. Don't do that. Don't write that. Don't copy that. Downvote it into correction, or, if uncorrected, into oblivion. Besides, "ar is a pointer because it is an array"?? What now??

Comment: If you were so scared, you would have explained why you don't trust this code `char **p` but trust this `char ar[200]` both are random address....

Comment: I have programmed a proof of concept how your code overwrites another variable in the program. Cf. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a9c14e9bae022ac. This kind of errors is hard to find.

Comment: Here is an adpation to show your code working.(http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccb70f8406031368) In fact, I got your point. It is good to explain this now before you discover this kind of situation in real problems. Even tough, this situation doesn't have extra variables, you want to avoid this kind of error. My point is this code does not use global variables, so it is a way to understand pointers. Anyway thanks for your contribution. I really apreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad you corrected the undefined behavior. The second version is not only "safer" as opposed to "less safe", is is valid as opposed to invalid. I am also still very unhappy with some comments in the code: "// technically an array is a pointer, so char *ar and char[] are the same" is plain wrong (except as declarations of function arguments).-- Btw, you can address comments to people so that they are notified by using the @-Syntax, like @RonaldoFelipe.

Comment: I didn't change for you only Mr @PeterA.Schneider. I changed for everyone who is going to read the comments section and this link (https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays)